# React.Lazy and React.Suspense don´t fix the problem of reducing unused javascript code, LCP problem in PageSpeed Insights

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I applied the solution proposed by PageSpeed Insights to solve one of the issues that is repeating in all the pages in my website: "Reduce the unused javascript code".

I suspense the footer and the scroll back button in order to minimize their impact.

When I tested it in PageSpeed Insights again I saw that the problem was still there.

Here is the code and the problem:

[lazy load components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz1Z6.png)

[checking the execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKlis.png)

[suspense the scroll button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN6Pi.png)

And the problem:

[PageSpeed Insights report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU7BC.png)

Any thoughts on this?

Am I using React.Lazy or React.Suspense wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO! Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

About the missing benefit from using code splitting: are you sure that you used suspence on the right components? Are these components the ones that include this unused libraries? For example: I think you are including `smoothscroll-polyfill` for every browser instead of loading it asynchronously only when needed

Comment: The library I lazy load (gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll), in the package has: require (smoothscroll-polyfill). I deleted it and in my local project i can run gatsby build with no errors but in netlify it gives me an error in build.